# partially missing tiles in Android MapView if you rotate - log shows IOException, EOFException in DataInputStream.readFully

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapactivity

First off, my issue is unlike the various API-key related MapView tile issues, and it also does not match [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848024/android-mapview-parts-of-map-missing) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772980/android-mapview-partially-loading-tiles), albeit it does have similarities.

Sometimes I encounter that a couple of tiles fail to load, leaving empty grey spots on the Android MapView.
LogCat shows this:

```
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978): IOException processing: 26
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978): java.io.EOFException
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:267)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:212)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readImageData(BaseTileRequest.java:194)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:124)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
05-15 11:55:01.178: W/System.err(11978):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
05-15 11:55:01.188: W/System.err(11978):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

This can be reproduced in a barebones app containing only a MapView when you rotate the device while moving and zooming around on the map. It does not happen all the time, though. Maybe there is some kind of race condition.

```
package my.TestApp;

import com.google.android.maps.*;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity  {

MapView mapView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="MyApiKeyGoesHere"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```